# Wifi/Mobile data required for MTP Connection/ transfer via USB cable?

Tags: android, usb, samsung-mobile, mtp, mobile-data

Does doing a USB/(MTP connection) for transferring photos from my Samsung S10 to PC use up my mobile's data or require WIFI?

I am running low on mobile data and can not connect to wifi. Wanted to make sure before plugging it in.

Sorry, do not know much about MTP connections, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No mobile data is not required for transferring filed via USB/MTP connection